# How to set timeout to pyplot.show() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python's `matplotlib` to draw figures.

I want to draw a figure with a timeout, say 3 seconds, and the window will close to move on the code.

I have known that `pyplot.show()` will create a blocking window with unlimited timeout; `pyplot.show(block=False)` or `pyplot.draw()` will make the window non-blocking. But what I want is let the code block for some seconds.

I have come up an idea that I might use an event handler or something, but still not really clear how to solve this. Is there any simple and elegant solution?

Suppose my code is like the following:

Draw.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Draw something
plt.show() #Block or not?
```

Comment: `sleep` doesn't work?

Comment: Well, I don't know where to put sleep... Do you mean I should put sleep before or after show()?

Comment: Sorry for multiple modifications few minutes ago... I'm not familiar with the interface of StackOverflow yet.... Now I am done with my modifications.

Comment: I see understand your question now. I don't know. :/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a simple example where I have created a timer to set your timeout and performed closing of window `plot.close()` in the callback function of the timer. Start the timer before `plot.show()` and after three seconds timer invokes `close_event()` and then continues with the rest of the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def close_event():
    plt.close() #timer calls this function after 3 seconds and closes the window 

fig = plt.figure()
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval = 3000) #creating a timer object and setting an interval of 3000 milliseconds
timer.add_callback(close_event)

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

timer.start()
plt.show()
print("I am doing something else")
```

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This did not work for me on **Mac OSX**.

Looks like there are two issues:

1. Calling `plt.close()` is not enough to exit the
   program `sys.exit()` works.
2. The scheduled function seems to be called at startup.
   This results in a display time of zero. The window
   pops and disappears at the same time. Using state in
   the callback that treats the first call differently
   solves this problem. An instance of a class with the
   special method `__call__()` is a good approach for such
   a stateful callable.

This works for me:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class CloseEvent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = True

    def __call__(self):
        if self.first:
            self.first = False
            return
        sys.exit(0)


fig = plt.figure()
timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=3000)
timer.add_callback(CloseEvent())


plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

timer.start()
plt.show()
print("Am doing something else")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import threading
def plt_show_sec(duration: float = 3):
    def _stop():
        time.sleep(duration)
        plt.close()
    if duration:
        threading.Thread(target=_stop).start()
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(duration)
plt_show_sec(3)#show for 3 sec
```